# HTTP::Daemon: How to set a custom value for Server in HTTP-Header?

Tags: perl, http, http-daemon

I am using `HTTP::Daemon` for a HTTP-server.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTTP::Daemon;

my $d = HTTP::Daemon->new (Listen => 1, LocalPort => 8080, ReuseAddr => 1, Blocking => 0) or die "error daemon: " . $!;
while (1)
{
    my $c = $d->accept ();
    if (defined ($c))
    {
        my $req = $c->get_request ();
        my $res = HTTP::Response->new (200);
        $res->header ("Server" => "MyServer");   # try to overwrite the internel builtin value
        $res->content ("OK");
        
        $c->send_response ($res);
        $c->autoflush ();
        undef ($c);
    }
    sleep (1);
}
```

I try to overwrite the HTTP-header entry for Server.
But, all I get is a 2nd entry with my value "MyServer".

Any idea how to overwrite the original value "libwww-perl-daemon"?

There is a method `product_tokens` for getting the value, but it is not able to set the value.

Comment: *"There is a method product_tokens for getting the value, but it is not able to set the value."* - as [documented](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Daemon#$d-%3Eproduct_tokens) the *"main reason to have this method is that __subclasses__ can __override__ it if they want to use another product name."*. Thus, subclass HTTP::Daemon and override this method if you want a different value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs say you should make a subclass:

> =item $d->product_tokens
>
> Returns the name that this server will use to identify itself.  This
> is the string that is sent with the C response header.  The
> main reason to have this method is that subclasses can override it if
> they want to use another product name.
>
> The default is the string "libwww-perl-daemon/#.##" where "#.##" is
> replaced with the version number of this module.

So, you write a small subclass and then use your subclass to make the object:

```
use v5.12;
package Local::HTTP::Daemon {
    use parent qw(HTTP::Daemon);

    sub product_tokens { 
        ... # whatever you want
        }
    }


my $d = Local::HTTP::Daemon->new( ... );
```